# as3 detect collision of a sprite with letters inside a page of text

Tags: actionscript-3, collision, bitmapdata, getpixel

I would like to use bitmapdata to detect collision of a sprite with letters inside a page of text. I have tried to do it with `getPixels` and test for the color but it seems that it's not accurate enough. I don't try hit test collision with bitmapdata because I don't know how to look for the black pixels only.

Comment: You can use BitmapData.draw to draw any DisplayObject to BitmapData, then you should be able to use BitmapData.hitTest to do collision detection http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/